# Question on Induction on Sums

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm confused about the step when you are proving the "$n+1$" case after you have used the inductive assumption and need to add the remaining part of the sum. For example, I had a problem where the left hand side was $\sum_{i=1}^{2(k+1)} i = $ and I was trying to break it up after using the inductive assumption, but I was confused on how to do that. I believe it came out to the $original$ $sum + (2k+1) + (2k+2)$. I don't know if I'm missing something with the summation notation, as it seems like I'm more confused with breaking up and working with summations. Thanks

Th original problem was to prove: $\sum_{i=1}^{2n} i = n(2n+1)$

Comment: Sorry but what is the question behind the story?

Comment: I was confused how it was broken down into (the original sum)+(2k+1)+(2k+2). Was that not clear from the post? I'm not providing you a story, I'm trying to give you background to my question.

Comment: Well, we don't know what the original sum was. And no, not clear to me, maybe to others. In any case, yes, you can break it up like that. If you tell us how you define sums (although I only know of one way), we can maybe help more.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear either.  Please explain what the sum is.

Comment: Ok, I added what I was originally proving.

Answer (score 0):

The principle of mathematical induction states that if you have a proposition $P_n$, a logical statement dependent on $n$, than you can prove that it holds for all natural numbers $n$ by showing that $P_1$ holds and that $P_k \implies P_{k+1}$. The essence of this is like a domino effect. If you have a sequence of dominos, and you show that the first one is knocked down, and that if one is knocked down, the next one will be knocked down, then we have proven that they will all be knocked down.

Resorting to your example, we will prove the following:
$$P_n: \qquad\qquad \sum_{m = 1}^{2n} m = n(2n+1) $$
**Base Case**: We see that:
$$ \sum_{m = 1}^2 m = 1 + 2 = 3 $$
$$ 1(2\cdot1 + 1)= 2 + 1 = 3 $$
Therefore, $P_1$ holds.

**Inductive Step**: Assume, for the sake of induction, that $P_k$ holds for some $k$.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m = 1}^{2k} m &= k(2k+1) \\
\sum_{m = 1}^{2(k+1)} m &= k(2k+1) + (2k+1) + (2k+2) \\
&= (k+1)(2k+1) + 2(k+1) \\
&= (k+1)(2k+3) \\
&= (k+1)\left[2(k+1) + 1 \right]
\end{align*}
Therefore, $P_k \implies P_{k+1}$.

**Conclusion**: We have shown:
$$ P_1 \wedge (P_k \implies P_{k+1}) $$
By mathematical induction, it follows that $P_n$ holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: The part I was unclear about was the second line of the inductive step. I thought it was (2k+2)+(2k+3) at the end.

Comment: The initial sum goes from m = 1 to 2k and the new sum goes from m = 1 to 2k+2. The terms added to the initial sum to get the new sum are (2k+1) and (2k+2).

Comment: This might be considered nitpicking (but I don't think it is): the first sentence of your inductive step should be "Let $k$ be an arbitrary natural number. Assume $P_k$ holds." or some variation of it (you don't want to assume that it holds for some $k$, we already know that).